# Creating a 2d colour gradient plot with 3 1D arrays

Tags: matplotlib, plot, colors, 2d

So i have 3 1D arrays, x_vals, y_vals and z_vals.

I would like to plot x_vals against y_vals, with z_vals defining the colour at the point.

from everything i have looked up it seems i need to use numpy.meshgrid, however when i try this python just times out.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: did the answer below help? if yes please accept it like described [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/4367286) ... if no, be more specific what you want ...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `LineCollection` command. Try this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# some data to plot
x = np.linspace(0,1,200)
y = np.sin(10*x)
z = x**2

# creating the segments
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

# creating LineCollection object
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'),norm=plt.Normalize(0, 1))
lc.set_array(z)
lc.set_linewidth(2)

# add LineCollection to plot
ax.add_collection(lc)

# set plotting range
ax.set_xlim((0,1))
ax.set_ylim((-1,1))

plt.show()
```